Remote Desktop to single session with independent authentication
I have a small number of Windows server machines S1-S5 and a similar number of client machines C1-C9.  All are joined to the same AD forest.  S1-S4 are Windows Server machines.
S5 is a Windows 10 machine (but can be ignored if that makes a solution difficult).  C1-C9 are a mixture of Windows 10 and Windows 11 machines.  The servers are not internet-accessible.
For various out-of-scope reasons, the server machines are each running a single session as a specific AD user account, call it SU1.  These sessions are normally unattended.
What I would like is to have a system whereby a user on one of the client machines authenticates as their own user, validated against a specific AD group (call it SG1), which then allows them to RDC into the existing session on one of the server machines, without supplying the password for SU1.
e.g. user CU1 is on C1 and is a member of SG1.  They can RDC into any of S1-S5 either without supplying additional authentication (implicit from their Windows login), or ideally reauthing as themselves perhaps including 2FA.  Either way, they connect to the existing session of SU1, not a new session as themselves, and don't need to know SU1's password.
Meanwhile user CU2 is on C2 and is not a member of SG1.  They cannot RDC into S1-S5 (unless they know the password of an account on that machine).
There is a firewall between the S and C computers that can block traffic based on membership in SG1, which may be sufficient.  But it would be nice to verify it at the server end as well, as defense in depth.
I don't care whether the remote access is "shared" with the local console on S1-S5 or not (i.e. blocking the local console like RDC does is fine), but it must be possible to log in remotely (like RDC can) if the session is logged in but not currently active (e.g. when the console is locked or subsequent to RDC disconnection).  It's not required to be able to log in remotely if there's no session at all (but it would be nice).
I'm ok with requiring distributing certificates or other files/settings to the individual client users, provided that the access can later be revoked by removing them from SG1 -- i.e. they can't be given anything equivalent to SU1's password on its own.

I'd prefer a solution using built-in Windows features, but am not entirely opposed to alternatives.  Windows Remote Assistance seemed promising at first, since it allows specifying an AD group that is allowed to connect, but it requires an attended session and will refuse to connect outright if the session is not active on the console (e.g. just after RDC).
I've also experimented with mstsc /v:S1 /shadow:1 but this uses dynamic ports rather than fixed ports (which is undesired) and behaves like Remote Assistance with regard to locked or otherwise unattended sessions (i.e. just appears "paused" until someone unlocks locally, or refuses to connect in the first place).
I also tried UltraVNC.  This supports authenticating against the group (which is good) but has some similar issues with locked sessions.  If I run the server in application mode, then it can't connect at all if the session is locked (e.g. after RDC), even if still logged in.  If I run the server in service mode, then it can connect if the session is locked but requires entering the SU1 password to get to the desktop.
Is there some way to configure one of these to better reflect what I want?  Or another method?


Is there some way to configure one of these to better reflect what I want? Or another method?

Since impersonation is not supported (in any way) in Windows, you will have to refer to 3rd party remote support tools. There is no way of knowing credentials but not knowning credentials.

I wonder if Apache Guacamole (https://guacamole.apache.org/) might work for you. You can control access to each connection by security group.
